# Can the experts Identify these sets, grey octagon platform and tan plates?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

A friend gave us a bunch of sets with only a few sets of instructions.  We were able to figure out a few of them.  Not sure what these are.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly, both pictures come from *[Set #79006 The Council of Elrond](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=79006-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*, but...

[image]

...Minifigure white chest piece comes from: *[Set Col03-15 Rapper, Series 3 (Complete Set with Stand and Accessories)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=col03-15#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.

[image]